# Async code seems to be running in parallel

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, mstest

Apologies in advance for the length of this question.
I'm writing a UWP app. Due to hardware platform constraints, the target is Windows 1703 (build 15063). The underlying model calls a WCF web service to interface with SQL server. 
I have a test method (MSTest) for my view-model that results in data being written to the database (via the web service). In the same test method I read the results back. Since this build of Windows does not support sql client, I have written another web service, purely for supporting my tests, that will query the database.
**The problem, in a nutshell, is that my database reads (using the support service) are happening before the writes!** I have verified this with SQL Server Profiler.
Of course everything is Async, but as far as I am aware the code should still execute in sequence.
Hopefully the code explains this better than I can:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Coolbox_Cage_ValidTest()
    {
        // Set up mocks etc...


        // Send a message to the view model. sessionViewModel will call a WFC web service to 
        // write to the DB.
        await sessionViewModel.SetInput(user, "Route-062-1");


        // If we wait for a second, the correct results are returned from the database.
        // If we don't, we get an early read where the results of SetInput have not yet been written.
        //await Task.Delay(1000);

        // GetResultsAsXDoc calls a different WCF web service to query the DB.
        XDocument xdoc = await GetResultsAsXDoc(client, "select * from STC_Box;");
        var q1 = from el in xdoc.Elements("DataSet").Elements("DataRow")
                 select el;

        // This assert will fail if we don't have the Task.Delay
        // Otherwise it succeeds.
        var b1 = from b in q1
                 where (string)b.Elements("Barcode").FirstOrDefault() == "062_S007743898_99_01"
                 && (string)b.Elements("Cage").FirstOrDefault() == "Route-062-1"
                 select b;
        Assert.IsTrue(b1.Count() == 1, "Did not find STC_Box record for 062_S007743898_99_01 in Cage 'Route-062-1'.");

    }


private async Task<XDocument> GetResultsAsXDoc(TestServices.TestServicesClient client, string sql)
{
    string xml = await client.GetDataXmlAsync(sql);
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    return xdoc;
}
```

The view model:

```
public async Task SetInput(User user, string input)
{
    // ...other stuff

    if (await loadCoolBoxIntoCage(user.UserID, rCoolbox, route)) { return; }

    // ...
}


private async Task<bool> loadCoolBoxIntoCage(string userID, CoolboxInputCode cb, RouteInputCode route)
{
    string msg = $"Is cool box {cb.ScanCode} being loaded into cage {route.ScanCode}?";
    DialogResult dialogResult = await _dialogService.GetYesNo(msg, "Confirm");
    if (dialogResult != DialogResult.Yes) return false;

    _despatchModel.LoadCoolBoxIntoCage(userID, cb.ScanCode, route.ScanCode);

    return true;
}
```

The Model:

```
        public async void LoadCoolBoxIntoCage(string userID, string CoolboxCode, string CageCode)
        {
            try
            {
                await Common.STC_LoadCoolBoxIntoCage(userID, CoolboxCode, CageCode);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }


// Common (Class Library)
    public static async Task STC_LoadCoolBoxIntoCage(string username, string Coolbox, string Cage)
    {
        // Local function delegate to call the service method
        async Task del(ScannerServicesClient client)
        {
            await client.STC_LoadCoolBoxIntoCageAsync(username, Coolbox, Cage);
        }

        // Call the service, passing the method
        await CallClient(del);

        // Done
        return ;
    }

/// <summary>
/// Gets a service client, does something with it, then disposes of it.
/// Properly (?) handles WCF errors.
/// This function exists mainly so we don't have to repeat this error-handling in separate routines
/// for every ScannerServicesClient method.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="doSomethingAsync">A delegate that performs some action with the client.</param>
/// <returns>Task</returns>
/// <see cref="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/use-close-abort-release-wcf-client-resources"/>
/// <see cref="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-call-wcf-service-operations-asynchronously"/>
private static async Task CallClient(Func<ScannerServicesClient, Task> doSomethingAsync)
{
    ScannerServicesClient client = Services.GetScannerServicesClient();

    try
    {
        // Get the service client
        await client.OpenAsync();

        // Do something with the client
        await doSomethingAsync(client);

        // Dispose the client.
        await client.CloseAsync();
    }
    catch (FaultException<DataCommandExecutionFault> e)
    {
        client.Abort();
        throw new Exception(e.Detail.Message);
    }
    catch (CommunicationException e)
    {
        client.Abort();
        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e)
    {
        client.Abort();
        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
    catch
    {
        client.Abort();
        throw;
    }
}
```

The main Web service method:

```
public void STC_LoadCoolBoxIntoCage(string username, string Coolbox, string Cage)
{
    using (var db = new Model.DbContext())
    {
        SqlParameter pReturnValue = CreateSqlParameter("RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int, null, ParameterDirection.Output); // ParameterDirection.ReturnValue does not work here!
        SqlParameter pUserID = CreateSqlParameter("UserID", SqlDbType.VarChar, username, ParameterDirection.Input);
        SqlParameter pCoolbox = CreateSqlParameter("Coolbox", SqlDbType.VarChar, Coolbox, ParameterDirection.Input);
        SqlParameter pCage = CreateSqlParameter("Cage", SqlDbType.VarChar, Cage, ParameterDirection.Input);

        var data = db.Database.SqlQuery<object>("exec @RETURN_VALUE = [dbo].[spSTC_LoadCoolBoxIntoCage2] @UserID, @Coolbox, @Cage;",
            pReturnValue, pUserID, pCoolbox, pCage);

        // Force the fetch of results (there are no results!)
        var result = data.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

and (finally!) the support service method:

```
public string GetDataXml(string sql)
{
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testDB"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            return reader2Xml(reader);
        }
    }
}


private string reader2Xml(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

    DataTable schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();

    XElement root = new XElement("DataSet", new XAttribute("FieldCount", reader.FieldCount),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"));


    int rowIndex = 0;

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        XElement dataRowElement = new XElement("DataRow", new XAttribute("Index", rowIndex++));

        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; ++i)
        {
            var ia = schema.Rows[i].ItemArray;  // schema row [i] describes data column [i]

            var oName = ia[0];
            var oType = ia[12];
            object cobj = reader[i];

            // Express NULL data by omitting the element.
            if (cobj != DBNull.Value)
            {
                dataRowElement.Add(new XElement(oName.ToString(), new XAttribute("Type", oType.ToString()), cobj.ToString()));
            }
        }

        root.Add(dataRowElement);
    }

    return root.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `_despatchModel.LoadCoolBoxIntoCage` is an async void which you do not await. Have you tried stepping through your code?

Comment: _"Since this build of Windows does not support sql client"_ - what does this mean? [SSMS 18.4 is supported from Windows 10 1607](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: CodeCaster, your first comment has hit the nail on the head. I think I got swamped in my own complexity. Post this as an answer.

Comment: As for your second comment, are you sure this is the case for UWP, Windows phone, .net core 1.4? Happy to concede you may be correct but I'm now too far down the path of a service-base architecture (which I've now grown to love :))